# Посчитать в каждом нечетном столбце количество элементов, принадлежащих промежутку

Tags: fortran

Эта программа в двумерном массиве ищет индексы двух одинаковых элементов, ну и сами элементы, как задать условие, чтобы она считала в каждом нечетном столбце количество элементов, принадлежащих промежутку `(pi^e;e^pi]`

```
program zad8
implicit none
integer,parameter :: m=4,n=5
integer A(m,n),i,k

print*, 'BBeDute ElemeNTbl massiva A'
do i=1,m 
read(*,*) (a(i,k), k=1,n)
end do

write(*,*) ' Matrix A' 
call print_matrix( a, m, n)
call found(a, m, n)

end program

subroutine print_matrix(a,m,n) 
integer i,k,m,n,a(m,n)

do i=1,m 
do k=1,n 
write(*,'(i4,1X,$)') A(i,k) 
end do 
write(*,'(/)') 
end do

return 
end subroutine

subroutine found(a, m, n)
integer i,k,l,j,m,n,a(m,n),q

do i=1,m
do j=i,m
do k=1,n
do l=k+1,n
if (A(i,k)==A(j,l)) then
q=A(j,l)
write(*,*) 'index'
write(*,'(2i2)') j,l
write(*,'(2i2)') i,k
end if

end do
end do
end do
end do
write(*,*)'ix znachenya matrix A=', q

return
end
```

Comment: Она странно ищет одинаковые элементы. Там должно быть куча сообщений "нушёл", когда i=j and k=l с последним заявлением 

    ix  znachenya matrix A= (значение A(m, n))

Comment: нужно условие с промежутком ,не обращайте внимание на то условие,что в прграмме

Comment: if(A[i,j] >= pi^e and A[i,j] <= e^pi)

Comment: а как в каждом нечетном столбце?

Comment: Начать с J = 1 и прибавлять 2

Answer (score 1):

```
integer q
double precision pi, e
pi=3.1415926535
e=2.718281828
q=0
do i=1,m
  do j=i,n
    if((i/2*2-i) != 0) then /* проверка на нечетность индекса i*/
       if(A[i,j] >= pi**e .and. A[i,j] <= e**pi) then
          q=q+A(i,j) /* суммируем */
       end if
    end if
  end do
end do
```

Как то так

Comment: не могли бы в программу условие вставить,видимо что-то не то делаю,ибо не работает